# Traer archivo .mp3 que conocida con dichos números

Tags: html5, codeigniter

quiero traer archivos .mp3 que se encuentra en el directorio **assets/grabaciones/**. Para esto solo tengo el siguiente nombre **20180502-163053** y el nombre de mi archivo que quiero traer se llama **20180502-163053-out.mp3**.

¿Cómo le hago para que coincida hasta **20180502-163053** y no tome en cuenta el **–out**?

Tengo mi siguiente código donde le paso fija la dirección, pero lo que necesito es que traiga el que cumpla con la anterior pregunta.

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="<?= base_url()?>assets/grabaciones/20180502-163053-out.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

segun lo que me comentas te tengo esta otra solucion

utiliza esta funcion para obtener todos los archivos de tu directorio

```
function obtenerListadoDeArchivos($directorio, $recursivo=false){

  // Array en el que obtendremos los resultados
  $res = array();

  // Agregamos la barra invertida al final en caso de que no exista
  if(substr($directorio, -1) != "/") $directorio .= "/";

  // Creamos un puntero al directorio y obtenemos el listado de archivos
  $dir = @dir($directorio) or die("getFileList: Error abriendo el directorio $directorio para leerlo");
  while(($archivo = $dir->read()) !== false) {
    // Obviamos los archivos ocultos
    if($archivo[0] == ".") continue;
    if(is_dir($directorio . $archivo)) {
      $res[] = array(
        "Nombre" => $directorio . $archivo . "/",
        "Tamaño" => 0,
        "Modificado" => filemtime($directorio . $archivo)
      );
      if($recursivo && is_readable($directorio . $archivo . "/")) {
        $directorioInterior= $directorio . $archivo . "/";
        $res = array_merge($res, obtenerListadoDeArchivos($directorioInterior, true));
      }
    } else if (is_readable($directorio . $archivo)) {
        $res[] = array(
          "Nombre" => $directorio . $archivo,
          "Tamaño" => filesize($directorio . $archivo),
          "Modificado" => filemtime($directorio . $archivo)
        );
    }
  }
  $dir->close();
  return $res;
}
```

utiliza esa funcion para obtener los archivos de tu directorio esto te devolvera un array ahora recorre este array y comparalo con el nombre que obtienes de la base de datos

```
$archivos=obtenerListadoDeArchivos('assets/grabaciones/',false)

$achivoreal="";//este sera el nombre de tu archivo
foreach($archivos as $item){
  if(str_replace(str_replace($item["nombre"],'-out'),'-in')==[datos db]){
      $achivoreal=$item["nombre"];
  }
}
```

Comment: 20180502-163053 este dato lo traigo de la BD pero lo malo es que no a fuerzas es -out, sino que luego trae -in. por eso solo quiero traer el que conocida con los dijitos de la pregunta

Comment: el nombre yo se lo puse directamente pero  quiero hacer para que lo traiga dinamicamente, que conocida con los primero dijitos no importa lo que traiga detras

Comment: modifique mi respuesta talvez te funcione por lo que me cuentas que necesitas